# How can I make a bar chart in OpenOffice Calc where the bars have two different colors to signify two different types of products?

Tags: charts, openoffice-calc

I'm sure most people have seen the Intel vs. AMD charts that places like TomsHardware.com use, but just in case you haven't, here is my chart:

[image]

I want the PV bars in black, and the Solar Hot Water bars to be red.  I've thought up a way to do this, but it would be mildly difficult, and I'm looking for a more straightforward approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feel rather stupid for not figuring out how to do this originally.  All you have to do is double-click the chart, then click on the bar that you want to change the color of a few times until only that bar (and not all of the bars) is highlighted.  From there, you can just double-click once again and change only that bar.

It's a lot of clicking, though, so perhaps a two-column, 100% overlap approach would be better for huge sets of data.